# using drop_first=False in a regression with dummies

Tags: pandas, regression, statsmodels

For a regression analysis I've created dummies for each month and use `drop_first=True` which takes out the first one (April in this case).
However, when showing the results to a public it is hard to understand for some people that the dummies have to be compared to the absent dummy variable (April).
Is it okay to work with `drop_first=False` as long as the coefficients in the regression are not impacted massively?

This is part of my code:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data=df['month'],drop_first=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to work with `drop_first=False` if your model does not have an intercept. In this case, the coefficient for each dummy, is the intercept for each category (or month in your case).